# Nodejs creating dictionary with multiple values error

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a dictionary for verified addresses. But I am getting an error. How do I fix this?

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

```
const Addresses = {
    {
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000": "BURN", 
        "Verified": "Yes"
        "Type": "Address"
    },
    {
        "0x1010101010101010101010101010101010101010": "BURN", 
        "Verified": "No"
        "Type": "Address"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the variable type from json to object and add commas.
so like this.

```
const Addresses = [
    {
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000": "BURN", 
        "Verified": "Yes",
        "Type": "Address"
    },
    {
        "0x1010101010101010101010101010101010101010": "BURN", 
        "Verified": "No",
        "Type": "Address"
    }
]
```

{ ... } => [ ... ]

`... : "Yes",`

`... : "No",`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you left out 2 commas resulting in a [syntax error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_token)

```
const Addresses = {
    {
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000": "BURN", 
        "Verified": "Yes",
        "Type": "Address"
    },
    {
        "0x1010101010101010101010101010101010101010": "BURN", 
        "Verified": "No",
        "Type": "Address"
    }
}

(added commas after "Yes" and "No")
```

Comment: I tried and I am still getting that error.

Comment: Are you trying to loop through the Addresses object?

Comment: Also Object type requires `key: value` pairs.
You can update the variable as array value.

Comment: I dont understand you question I am trying to create a dictionary so I can use the info for my project later on.

Comment: Usually you will loop through the data. Try making the Addresses object an array instead like so:

const Addresses = [ ]